# How to find median of multiple arrays in MPI

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, mpi, median

There are some of MPI nodes and each MPI nodes have some arrays.
Each arrays are different size and unsorted.

Total size of arrays is about 10 Million. (10,000,000)

I can find median of each arrays. it's easy.

but, I want to find median of total arrays. not for each.
and it cannot merge, because, it's huge size.

For example, MPI node: 3, Total Size of Arrays: 11

MPI node 1's array: [1,5,6,10]

MPI node 2's array: [9,3,11,34]

MPI node 3's array: [5,20,10]

if total array is [1,5,6,10,9,3,11,34,5,20,10] -> find median

Comment: The `c` doesn't make sense here

Comment: There is no easy way, but it can still be done as a multi-step operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't merge those arrays in a single set then there is no way to get the median, to get an approximate median you can use the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm.

Take a look to [Median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)

Comment: Cool - btw: `now way` -> `no way` I guess

Comment: Of course there's a way: select the first number from the sub-array on one process.  Send it to every other process.  Each process counts how many numbers are larger, how many smaller, and reports back.  Repeat until done.  For a quicker program, first create a histogram, ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, counting how many numbers are larger and how many are smaller than the first one doesn't give you the median.

Comment: And I don't get why are you suggesting an histogram, OP wants the median `{(n + 1 )/2}th item` of those arrays merged in one set, not the median from a grouped frequency